# avoid duplicated calls in SQL - st_distance_sphere

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to avoid calling st_distance_sphere twice (given how expensive it is for larger queries).

Any ideas on how best to avoid calling twice as is in the example query below?

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       ST_Distance_Sphere(table1.location, table2.location)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (...)  -- what's in this bit isn't relevant
INNER JOIN table2 ON ST_Distance_Sphere(table1.location, table2.location) <= 50
```

Comment: Are you sure it's being called twice? Could you share the query plan of both queries? (with and without `ST_Distance_Sphere` call in the SELECT)

Comment: Seems like you are using PostgreSQL, not MySQL...

Comment: Bear in mind it's the job of the optimizer to find opportunities to reduce costs by eliminating duplicate calls to deterministic functions. You shouldn't need to help it by convoluting your query. In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

Comment: the inner join part if the distance should be in a where clause, but you can chekc the query plans and compare